# populate SQL table by reading tweets from dictionary within a dictionary using Python

Tags: python, twitter, dictionary, sqlite

I am trying to read 1000 tweets from a file.

```
http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/Twitter_2013_11_12.txt
```

The tweets are stored on line-by-line basis.
I have to create a SQL table for the 'geo' entry. 'Geo' is a dictionary inside the tweets dictionary. In some cases dictionary 'geo' is completely blank and in come cases it has values. I need to keep track of how many Geo dictionaries are blank, and how many have vlaues. I need to generate a unique ID for that table. In addition to the ID column, the geo table should have “type”, “longitude” and “latitude” columns. If Geo dictionary has values, it looks like this:

```
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [44.49241705, 11.33374359]}
```

Since I am new to Python and SQLITE, my code is basic (as I want to be able to understamd my code), and it is not working as expected. I am trying to do the insert in the Geo table if the length of geo dictionary is greater than 1, but it is not working. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2, time, json, sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('Tweets_Database_A6.db')
c = conn.cursor()
wFD = urllib2.urlopen('http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/Twitter_2013_11_12.txt')

numLines = 1000
tweets = []
while numLines > 0:
    line = wFD.readline()
    numLines = numLines - 1
    try:    
         tweets.append(json.loads(line))
    except:
        print line
wFD.close()   

#create geo table using sqlite3
TblGeo = """create table Geo(Id number, Type text, Longitude number, latitude number);"""
c.execute(TblGeo) 

HasGeo=0
NoGeo=0
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet_geo = tweet['geo']
    if len(tweet_geo) > 1:
        HasGeo = HasGeo+1
    try:            
        c.execute("insert into Geo(id, Type, Longitude, Latitude) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" %(HasGeo, tweet_geo['type'], tweet_geo['coordinates'][0], tweet_geo['coordinates'][1]))               
    except:
        print "no entry for " , i
    else:
        NoGeo = NoGeo+1

print HasGeo, " ", NoGeo
```

Comment: sorry about the typo @Oleg9, can you please guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say this script doesn't work, do you mean it runs and gives a result you don't expect, or does it crash with an error? If there is an error, what is it? I have a guess about this but I need to know if you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing for a few reasons. Since this appears to be an assignment, I will not post the working code here, but I will attempt to point you in the right direction. Here are some of the things I've noticed while testing your code:

1. You made the assumption that tweet['geo'] would be an empty string. It actually is not. Essentially, the data sets this value to a json "null" when no geo information is available; this gets translated to the Nonetype in python, and not an empty string. Therefore, you should not be checking for the length of that value, but rather whether that value is True (hint: python considers '', "", [], ,{}, None as False)
2. I don't think your indentation on lines 28-31 is correct. Shouldn't that logic execute in the if block? right now, you are always executing that code, which I think is a logical error.
3. In your exception trapping at line 31, where do you define the variable "i"?

I hope this is helpful; feel free to ask additional clarifications if you are stumped.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I am able to populate the table now.